# Wrong printout with assymble code

Tags: assembly, logic, helper

I have a problem on the **print** on my code that i couldn't solve ..

my program is simple acutely it's a practice on how to draw a simple linear eqn

the x is constant between -2 and 2

and the user must enter a & b in the linear eqn y=ax+b.

a & b are signed the user must also enter the sign

and the program must give five pairs of (y,x) ,but it's not working for me

and here is the code :

```
{

    ; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
    ; add your data here!

    x   db -2,-1,0,1,2
    r1  dw 0,0,0,0,0
    r2  dw 0,0,0,0,0
    z1  dw 0,0,0,0,0
    z2  dw 0,0,0,0,0 
    a1  db 0 
    a2  db 0
    b1  db 0
    b2  db 0

    m1 db "This program will give u 5 pairs of result for the following eqn 'y=ax+b' where x is between -2 & 2.",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh
    m2 db 0ah,0dh,"Enter the sign of 'a',(+,-)",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh
    m3 db 0ah,0dh,"Enter 'a'",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh
    m4 db 0ah,0dh,"Enter the sign of 'b',(+,-)",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh
    m5 db 0ah,0dh,"Enter 'b'",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh  


ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; add your code here 

    lea dx, m1
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    lea dx, m2
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    xor ax,ax

    mov ah, 1     ;entering the sign of "a"
    int 21h        

    CMP al,'-'

    jnz next

    lea dx, m3
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1     ;entering "a"
    int 21h
    sub al,30h

    neg al

    mov a1,al  
    xor ah,ah
    xor si,si
    mov cx,5

mul1: 

    mov al,a1

    imul x[si] 

    mov r1[si],ax   ;saving the result from multiplying "-ax" 

inc si    

    loop mul1 
    jmp b 


 next:  ;if "a" was pasitive 

    lea dx, m3
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1     ;entering "a"
    int 21h
    sub al,30h

    mov a2,al

    xor ah,ah
    xor si,si
    mov cx,5 


mul2:

    mov al,a2

    imul x[si] 

    mov r2[si],ax   ;saving the result from multiplying "ax" 

    inc si    

    loop mul2  


 b: lea dx, m4
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1     ;entering the sign of "b"
    int 21h 

    CMP al,'-'

    jnz next1

    lea dx, m5
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 

    mov ah, 1     ;entering "b"
    int 21h
    sub al,30h 

    mov b1,al

    xor ah,ah
    xor si,si
    mov cx,5  

sub1:

    mov al,b1

    sub ax,r1[si] 

    mov z1[si],ax   ;saving the result from the op "ax-b" 

    inc si    

    loop sub1

    jmp print1    

next1: 

    lea dx, m5
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 

    mov ah, 1     ;entering "b"
    int 21h 
    sub al,30h

    mov b2,al

    xor ah,ah
    xor si,si
    mov cx,5  

add1:

    mov al,b2 

    add ax,r2[si] 

    mov z2[si],ax   ;saving the result from the op "ax+b" 

    inc si    

    loop add1

    jmp print2

;printing the 5 pairs (x,y) when ax-b

print1:

    xor si,si
    mov cx,5

    print: 

    mov dl,0ah
    mov ah,2
    int 21h

    mov dl,0dh
    mov ah,2
    int 21h

    mov dl,'('
    mov ah,2
    int 21h


    lea dx,x[si]
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov dl,","
    mov ah,2
    int 21h 

    lea dx,z1[si]
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov dl,")"
    mov ah,2
    int 21h  

    mov dl,0ah
    mov ah,2
    int 21h

    mov dl,0dh
    mov ah,2
    int 21h

    inc si

    loop print
    jmp end1


print2: ;printing the 5 pairs (x,y) when ax+b  

    xor si,si
    mov cx,5 

    print11:

    mov dl,0ah
    mov ah,2
    int 21h

    mov dl,0dh
    mov ah,2
    int 21h 

    mov dl,"("
    mov ah,2
    int 21h


    lea dx,x[si]
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov dl,","
    mov ah,2
    int 21h 

    lea dx,z2[si]
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov dl,")"
    mov ah,2
    int 21h

    mov dl,0ah
    mov ah,2
    int 21h

    mov dl,0dh
    mov ah,2
    int 21h 

    inc si

    loop print11  

end1 :

    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.

}
```

and thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
m1 db "This program will give u 5 pairs of result for the following eqn 'y=ax+b' where x is between -2 & 2.",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh
m2 db 0ah,0dh,"Enter the sign of 'a',(+,-)",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh
m3 db 0ah,0dh,"Enter 'a'",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh
m4 db 0ah,0dh,"Enter the sign of 'b',(+,-)",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh
m5 db 0ah,0dh,"Enter 'b'",0ah,0dh,"$",0ah,0dh
```

In all of these lines the last CRLF pair will not be printed because it comes after the terminating **$**. Is this your PRINT problem?

```
m3 db 0ah,0dh,"Enter 'a'",0ah,0dh,0ah,0dh,"$"
```

This is a problem. You defined **x** as byte and **r1** as word. You cannot use `inc si` to properly advance in both. I suggest you define **x** as word and use `add si,2`.

```
mul1: 
 mov al,a1
 imul x[si] 
 mov r1[si],ax   ;saving the result from multiplying "-ax" 
 inc si    
 loop mul1
```

Comment: the actual problem is in the last result when i want to print y

Comment: When print you forget to convert the integer into a string. `lea dx,x[si]` 
`mov ah,9` `int 21h` This DOS function expects a **$-terminated text string**

Comment: how can i convert it ?

Comment: Write a routine that repeatedly divides the number by 10 until the quotient becomes 0. On each iteration you store the remainder+48 in decreasing memory addresses. Many examples exist on this forum.